# Why can't Web Publish/Deploy Find my Web.config?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, orchardcms, webdeploy, msbuild-wpp

I've just clone OrchardCMS from codeplex, built it and tried to deploy it to my web hosting service using Visual Studio's 'Publish' command.

No files get published and the publish fails with the following error:

```
1>------ Publish started: Project: Orchard.Web, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2352,5): Error : Could not open Source file: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Tim\targetsite.co.uk\src\Orchard.Web\Media\web.config;Media\web.config'.
1>
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 5 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've checked the source code, and the file is there and in the correct folder. So what's this error message actually trying to tell me? What's going on here and how do I fix it?

Comment: before anyone asks, I know my publishing profile has correct settings for the ISP. WebMatrix happily publishes the files using the same settings.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug. It's already been reported and is being addressed now:

- http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/19264
- http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/19282

The second report proposes a workaround that might help you out till this get fixed.